# EF one to many where condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have generated below two classes using Entity Framework

```
public class Persons
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int personId { get; set; }   
    //NAVIGATIONL PROP. 
    public virtual ICollection<streetLivedIn> { get; set; }
}

public class StreetLivedIn
{      
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
   //NAVIGATIONL PROP. 
    public virtual PersonId (Foriegn Key with Person)
}
```

There is a One-to-Many relation between Person and Street Lived In.I am trying to pull a list of persons whose `AddressType`, in `streetlivedin` table, is "Home".For this I have the below statement

```
var Lstpersons = db.persons()
                   .Include(x => x.streetlivedin)
                   .Where(x => x.streetlivedin.AddressType == "Home");
```

The above code throws an error in where clause saying it cannot convert `ICollection<streetlivein>` to `streetlivedin` class.

I would like to know how can i achieve this using Include and where.And using Persons context.(I know it can be easily achieved using streetLivedIn context..
like

```
var Lstpersons = db.streetlivedin()
                   .Include(x => x.person)
                   .Where(x => x.streetlivedin.AddressType == "Home");
```

(No join statements....Please)

Comment: So you're fine with `.Include()` but not `.Join()`?  Care to explain why?

Comment: @DavidL We are using Include in the rest of the code functionalities.So to stay consistent...

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to get find where `streetlivedin.AddressType == "Home"` but `streetlivedin` is a collection on the person entity. Instead, do a sub-query on `streetlivedin`, for example:

```
var Lstpersons = db.persons()
                   .Include(x => x.streetlivedin)
                   .Where(x => x.streetlivedin.Any(y=>y.AddressType == "Home"));
```

Comment: doesn't 'any' returns addresstypes that aren't home too....along with the home address type?

Comment: `Any` returns a bool for items that match the expression, so as long as the person has one `streetlivedin` of home, it will return that person. Or are you just after the home addresses for each person?

Comment: I need person along with streetLivedIn details..too

Comment: This should return the person with that `streetlivedin` records.

Comment: Steve's answer is correct. The query will return all persons that have a "Home" address, but each matching Person object will include all addresses associated with that person.

Comment: Let us say a Person has "Home" and "Office" addresstypes...doesn't using 'Any' returns both records..?i want it to return only "Home" record

Comment: So, in other words, you only want `Home` addresses? Why don't you want to just use the `streetlivedin` DbSet?

Comment: @JoelMueller is there a way to restrict the returned addresses associated to only "Home"?

Comment: Yes you can, but I don't think you can by using the navigation property. Think of it this way: the navigation property is just an easy way of generating an inner join between Person and Address. If you want to apply extra conditions to the join (only "Home" addresses) then you have to create the join between the two tables yourself instead of using the navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

```
int id=1;
var Lstpersons=(from s in db.streetlivedins  where s.AddressType == "Home" && s.PersonId ==id select s).ToList();
```

If  you don't want specific user address

```
var Lstpersons=(from s in db.streetlivedins  where s.AddressType == "Home" select s).ToList();
```

If you want persons

```
var Lstpersons=(from p in db.persons  let st =p.streetlivedins from s in st where s.AddressType == "Home" select p).ToList();
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier in post..I don't want to use db.streetlivedins...I would like to achieve using db.persons and that too with include statment..not "from..in...join.."

Comment: very weird that why you wouldn't want to use `db.streetlivedins`,  you do not gain anything by not using it, so consistency in using `include` or the parent table is a bit ridiculous. You should focus on the architecture and the repository for consistency, not this.

Comment: @AD.Net Iam using repository class for each model.I have already instantiated persons repository class for other functionalities.I don't want to instantialte a StreetLivedIn repository class just for this ...So I am trying to see If I can acheive using person repository class

Answer (score 1):

To get all the people with only their home address, you'd want a query something like this.

```
from person in db.persons()
join address in db.streetlivedin() on person.personId equals address.PersonId
where address.AddressType == "Home"
select new { Person = person, HomeAddress = address }
```

Of course, since that's an inner join, any person with more than one Home address would show up more than once in the results.

As an aside, the mixed capitalization would drive me nuts if I had to work with that codebase. You don't have to follow the C# coding conventions, but if you're going to pick your own convention at least make it consistent.